# How to make the "Activity" tab appear for Customer Community Plus Users?

Tags: sobject, customer-community-plus, activity-timeline

I have Customer Community Plus users set up and have used contact shares to grant access to the appropriate contacts.

On the contact detail page, however, the "Activity" tab is missing. When I assign the same Page Layout used by the community plus users to another Salesforce user, the "Activity" tab is showing so I don't think it's a problem with the layout, but maybe other permissions?

How can I make the "Activity" tab appear for Customer Community Plus Users?

---

Other things I've tried/other possibly relevant details:

I have come across [this answer](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000lbXvQAI) which indicates that even though my org wide defaults are set to use the Activity Timeline instead of Related List, as these are community users I can't log in as them to access their settings to check if the Summer '19 release has flipped their settings - is there another way to check this?

The object permissions for the profile List Events as "object permissions = --, Total fields = 63, Tab Settings = --, Page Layouts = Varies by Record Type". According to [this table](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5) under the heading "License Detail", Community Plus users should have "Read, Create, Edit, Delete" options for the Event and Task objects but when I edit the Event object permissions on the profile the whole "Object Permissions" section is missing. I tried cloning the profile but this option still does not show up.

This is the page layout using a salesforce platform user:
[image: Activity Tab Present]

This is the page layout using the customer community plus user:
[image: Activity Tab Absent]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Community builder to drag the activities component.

The communities pages are different than the record pages in lightning experience.

The good news is the activity timeline component is also available in the community builder. Drag and drop the component shown below and publish the changes

[image]

Note that permissions for **events and Tasks** are in ***General Permission*** section of the profile

Comment: Ah yes thank you! So the component was already added to the communities page (Generic Record Page), but there was an option on the right to change Tab 2 to be "Activity Timeline" rather than "Related Records" (like the link I put in the question advised) which revealed the Activity tab that I was looking for. So thank you this was where I needed to look for the Activity Timeline option.